# How to instruct VeraCrypt to use my hardware entropy source

Tags: encryption, randomness

As a hobby I built a radioactive decay based RNG, that I am still perfecting.
I would like to know how to use its output to contribute to VC entropy pool for key generation.
I know that before considering my device secure, there are many steps to accomplish.
For now it is just a hobby project.

I found the command --random-source for VC but I can't seem to find any documentation on it.

Comment: Hiya & welcome. Any details of your device anywhere?

Comment: Hello! It is based on arduino and a geiger muller tube kit: it compares time intervals between decay events to generate random bits, whitens them with the Von Neumann algorithm, and saves them in a file on a SD card.